# Скрытие экрана от пользователя при удаленном к нему подключении

Tags: c#, remote-access

Всем заранее спасибо.

Мне нужно во время удаленного подключения к пользователю скрывать иногда от него экран. Что нибудь вроде того, как в TeamViewer - черный экран и блокировка клавы\мыши.

Первоначально я просто выключал монитор у сервера:
postMessage(0xFFFF, 0x112, 0xF170, 2)
С Windows 7 проходит отлично, но на ОС Windows 10 происходит выход из сеанса на экран авторизации.

Может как то можно избежать этого? Или может быть можно как то сделать второй виртуальный рабочий стол, который не будет отображаться на сервере, но зато будет доступен подключенному админу?

Comment: Использовать RDP.